# db2 removal of Generate always Expression on Timestamp data type

Tags: db2

I have a column `UPDATE_TIME` with an expression

```
 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP
```

How to remove the `Generated always` for timestamps?

I tried

```
  db2 "alter table xxxx alter column UPDATE_TIME drop expression"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid syntax.  You need to use,

```
 alter table xxxx alter column update_time drop generated
```

See the documentation on [alter table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F2-7-3-0-0-10) for more details.